# android post запросы на https

Tags: android, post, get, ssl, https

Отправляю `post` `get` запросы через приложение библиотекой JSONParser. Все прекрасно работало до тех пор пока сайт не перешел на `https`. После этого приложение перестало получать ответы от api. Посоветуйте как можно выйти из этой ситуации.
Вот пример кода как делаю запросы:

```
class GetCheckBanID extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, JSONObject> {
    /**
     * Перед началом показать в фоновом потоке прогресс диалог
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    /**
     * Получение детальной информации о продукте в фоновом режиме
     **/
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {

        // получаем продукт по HTTP запросу

        int success;
        JSONObject product = null;
        try {

            // Список параметров
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", '"'+android_id+'"'));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_ban_id, "GET", param);

            Log.d("prefLog", param.toString());

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // Успешно получинна детальная информация о продукте
                JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);

                // получаем первый обьект с JSON Array
                product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
                // покаываем данные о продукте в EditText
                checkBan = 4;
                Log.d("prefLog", "check ban android_id find");
            } else {
                checkBan = 1;
                Log.d("prefLog", "ban not found ander id");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return product;
    }

    /**
     * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем диалог прогресс
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject resault) {
        Log.d("myLog", "results === " + resault);

        new GetProductDetails().execute();
    }
}`
```

///ошибка

```js
05-30 18:01:00.774 2465-2465/widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo, PID: 2465
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo.Loader$GetProductDetails.onPostExecute(Loader.java:210)
                                                                                 at widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo.Loader$GetProductDetails.onPostExecute(Loader.java:150)
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5235)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
05-30 18:01:00.797 246-246/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/2465/oom_score_adj; errno=22
05-30 18:01:00.815 2113-3874/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '1e07696b widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo/widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo.Loader (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-30 18:01:00.817 2113-3874/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '1cdc8457 widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo/widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo.SplashScrin (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-30 18:01:06.894 1851-1851/? E/SearchServiceStarter: Task 132 failed or timed out. Client 8142280248464663 disconnecting from SearchService!
                                                       java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
                                                           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cI(SourceFile:75)
                                                           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:57)
                                                           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ce.n(SourceFile:2)
                                                           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.at.l(SourceFile:51)
                                                           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.av.run(SourceFile:5)
                                                           at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ay.run(SourceFile:2)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5235)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
05-30 18:01:06.908 1851-2173/? E/VelvetBackgroundTasksIm: Background task telemetry.request_logging_by_intent failed
                                                          java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
                                                              at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cI(SourceFile:75)
                                                              at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:69)
                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.bw.d.run(SourceFile:5)
                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.tasks.bk.run(SourceFile:5)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.at.run(SourceFile:18)
                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bh.run(SourceFile:4)
                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bh.run(SourceFile:4)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ag.run(SourceFile:6)
05-30 18:01:16.715 2113-3945/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=1,62 rxSuccessRate=8,60 targetRoamBSSID=any RSSI=-23
```

```
введите сюда код
```

///jsonParser init

```js
package widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo.parser;

import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // метод получение json объекта по url
    // используя HTTP запрос и методы POST или GET
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Создаем HTTP запрос
        try {

            // проверяем метод HTTP запроса
            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // пытаемся распарсить строку в JSON объект
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // возвращаем JSON строку
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка? Добавьте стектрейс в вопрос. И покажите код, как вы инициализируете `jsonParser`.

Comment: Https это секьюрный http, подписанный SSL сертификатом. Гуглите как ваш JSONParser подписать

Comment: 05-30 18:01:00.774 2465-2465/widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: widget.hardcoding.com.rukinoo, PID: 2465